# Significance of the Route Name in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, routes, .net-4.5

I was looking at the `Routing` Concepts of MVC and specifically at the below line:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // Route Pattern
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Default values.
 );
```

Everything's fine, but I don't get the significance of the `Route Name`.

Is it just a **term** out there ? or is there anything significant with it ?

Am I missing using it or where are the places it is used in MVC 4 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Am I missing using it or where are the places it is used in MVC 4 ?
```

There are Helper methods that use the route name.

See for example the [`RouteLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703603%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and [RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505215%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) methods :